# Select2 is not showing values in drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-select2

The drop down is not showing the values that I am getting from the ajax call. I think its not calling the formatResult function. I am not sure whats happening. It just shows 'Searching...'. Any clue will be helpful.

```
$("#abc").select2(
    {
        placeholder: "abc",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        multiple: true,
        formatResult: formatResult,
        ajax: { 
        url: "some url",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
        return {
            timermatch: "%"+term+"%"
        };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                console.log(value);
                return {
                       results: value
                      };
                    }));
                } 
          }
         });

  function formatResult(data) {
    console.log("value");
    return '<div>' + data + '</div>';
};
```

Comment: please provide an example of the received json.

Comment: The data is
{ VIEW : ABC,
 TIMER: VB,
 MANAGEMENT: DHC,
 NOTES: 201,
 USR: POPULATE }

Comment: that is not valid json! it has to be: {
    "VIEW": "ABC",
    "TIMER": "VB",
    "MANAGEMENT": "DHC",
    "NOTES": "201",
    "USR": "POPULATE"
}